# ReactJS – Map Data with Headings/Groups

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grouping

I've had a search around but can't seem to find anyone asking the same question, which surprises me.

Basically i'm trying to map out an array of objects that would look similar to this:

```
"objKey": {
     "date": "[timestamp]",
     "name": "Object Name",
     "description": "Object Description"
}
```

And I want to map it out to look like the following when rendered to the page:

```
Today: 
         Object One – Object Description
         Object Two – Object Description
         Object Three – Object Description

Tomorrow: 
         Object One – Object Description
         Object Two – Object Description
         Object Three – Object Description
```

Etc...

So usually I would just create a function the maps through the array and returns the values I want to display, but I not sure where to start looking for how to 'group' these objects by date?

I want to avoid reducing them into new arrays if possible, as it's going to get pretty messy that way, any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: What is today and tomorrow that is heading or need to format from timestamp date. If timestamp is after 2,3.. days what will be the heading

Comment: The date/day would always be the heading for example 'Tuesday 17 July' but on render it would replace the date for today with 'Today', and tomorrow with 'Tomorrow'

Answer (score 0):

you can try grouping with reduce method like this

```
const data = {
    "date": "wednesday 18 April 2018",
    "name": "React",
    "description": "lorem"
  }
const result = '';
    let grouping = Object.keys(data).reduce((cur,prev)=>{
      if(prev === 'date'){
        const date = new Date();
        const dateObj = new Date(data[prev]);
        const diff = dateObj.getTime() - date.getTime();
        const diffdays = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
        result = diffdays == 0 ? 'Today' : diffdays == 1 ? 'Tommorrow' : data[prev];
        cur[result] = {}
      }
      cur[result][prev] = data[prev];
      return cur
    },{})
    console.log(grouping)
    let value = Object.keys(grouping[result]).map((key)=>{
      return <li>{key + ' : '+ grouping[result][key]}</li>
    })
```

demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hkfa81?file=index.js)